# A non-interrogative sentence that starts with 'wenn'

Tags: translation

I have [come across](https://www.faz.net/aktuell/gesellschaft/menschen/warum-moore-wichtig-fuer-das-klima-sind-16710665-p4.html) this sentence:

> Moorbauern fahren derzeit also besser, wenn sie ihren Boden
>   trockenlegen, EU-Prämien abgreifen und offiziell wertvolle Flächen
>   bewirtschaften. **Wenn sie dem Klima schaden**.

Is the bolded sentence incomplete, e.g. missing an ending '*so sei es*' or something similar? If it's a complete sentence, then what kind of construction is this?

Comment: The simplest way to understand it is to imagine a comma instead of a full stop separating the two sentences.

Answer (score 3):

It's up to you if you think it's an error or an [ellipsis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis_(linguistics)). In both cases it's an incomplete sentence. Here is a version with a complete sentence:

> Moorbauern fahren derzeit also besser, wenn sie ihren Boden trockenlegen, EU-Prämien abgreifen und offiziell wertvolle Flächen bewirtschaften. **Moorbauern fahren derzeit also besser, ** wenn sie dem Klima schaden.

An ellipsis is a stylistic feature, that exists - as I believe - in all languages. To construct an ellipsis you just omit a part of speech that easily can be reconstructed be the reader/listener.

An example of a very well know ellipses is:

- Good morning
  instead of *"**I wish you a** good morning."*